# jQuery mouse wheel horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

Is there any way to detect if the mouse wheel is scrolling sideways in Javascript? I am now using the excellent jquery.mousewheel.3.0.2 plugin, but I couldn't find any relevant parameters on the event. Please help!

Comment: I feel discriminated, my mouse doesn't support this feature...

Comment: Neither does mine :D But customer is on one of them multi-touchie-trackpaddies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOMMouseScroll event has an "axis" property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events#Determining_the_scroll_direction

no idea about MSIE

Comment: Seems to be Firefox 3.5+ specific according to both Mozilla docs and a Closure comment. I take what I can get, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of JQuery MouseWheel plugin now suports horizontal scrolling as well as vertical one.